# Issue using extjs to display text containing double quotes

Tags: javascript, extjs, escaping

I am using `extjs` to display my data from database in which records also contain some special characters. When I am displaying the records, each record has a drop down field which shows the values containing specials characters. It shows those values with hex code of those special characters like:

Value coming from server like "Rohit's, Kumar" which is correct *I think* but initially `extjs` is showing it but when I save a row and then go to update that row again, now the drop down shows some value like this:

```
"Rohit&#34;s, Kumar"
```

Which is the wrong behavior. How do you prevent this in `extjs`?

Comment: Post the code/[fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor) for what you have tried so far.

Comment: Can you show the raw value from your backend? For me it looks somehow decoded, you can try to use Ext.htmlDecode('Rohit&#34;s, Kumar')